# Echarts - Default noDataLoadingOption option bubbles still displaying even though there is data

Tags: javascript, charts, echarts

I am trying to use [echarts](http://echarts.baidu.com/echarts2/doc/doc-en.html). In my chart, when there is no data it displays the noDataLoadingOption which is correct (as seen in the first image)
[image: First-Current]

But when I go to the next button (where there is data) 'Total Amount', it displays the data that looks like a background image, but also displays the noDataLoadingOption  with bubbles. The data is coming from the back end code using an Ajax call. Image below.[image: Second- Total]
 What puzzles me is, when there is data for the Current Month, the 'Total Amount' is displayed perfectly.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for this issue. The below code did the trick.

mychart.hideLoading();